# How to search the children of a HTMLDivElement?

Tags: javascript, dom

I have an `HTMLDivElement`, and my goal is to find a `div` nested beneath this.

Ideally I'd want something like `getElementById`, but that function doesn't work for `HTMLDivElement`.

Do I need to manually traverse the graph, or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/y9K9Y/

If the `<div>` you're searching for has a class, you can use `getElementsByClassName()`:

```js
document.getElementById( 'parentDiv' ).getElementsByClassName( 'childDiv' )[0];
```

If it doesn't have a class you can use `getElementsByTagName()`:

```
document.getElementById( 'parentDiv' ).getElementsByTagName( 'div' )[0];
```

And if it has an `id` you can, of course, just use `getElementById()` to find it no matter where it is in the DOM:

```
document.getElementById( 'childDiv' );
```

Comment: Don't extend `Element.prototype` with junk. There's a perfectly good `getElementsByClassName` method that does what you want but better.

Comment: @Raynos I thought that was document level only. Edited.

Comment: document.getElementById( 'parentDiv' ).querySelector('div')

Answer (score 8):

```
  //For immediate children 

  var children = document.getElementById('id').childNodes;

   //or for all descendants

   var children = document.getElementById('id').getElementsByTagName('*');
```

Answer (score 5):

```
var div = ...
var divChildren = div.getElementsByTagName("div");
var divYouWant = [].filter.call(divChildren, function (el) {
  return matchesSomeCondition(el);
});
```

> Ideally, I'd want something like getElementById

And you can use `getElementById` just do `document.getElementById(id)` and since ids are *unique* that will find that single div item you wanted.

You can also use `elem.getElementsByClassName` to select a descendant of elem by class

Answer (score 4):

You can use **[`.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)**.  The functions `getElementById()` and `getElementByClassName()` work perfectly fine on `document`, but they do not work on the child records returned by these functions.  If you need *many* children elements, then consider [**`.querySelectorAll()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

**Full Working Demo:**

```js
const topdiv = document.getElementById('top-div');
const seconddiv = topdiv.querySelector('#second-div');
seconddiv.innerHTML = '456';
```

```html
<div id="top-div">
123
<div id="second-div">
abc
</div>
</div>
```

**Demonstration of `getElementById()` Failing:**

```js
const topdiv = document.getElementById('top-div');
const seconddiv = topdiv.getElementById('second-div');
seconddiv.innerHTML = '456';
```

```html
<div id="top-div">
123
<div id="second-div">
abc
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Concise and readable:

```
document.getElementById('parentDiv').children[0];
```

Using `.childNodes` returns lots of extra children, whereas `.children` returns a smaller array.